# Can I claim compensation on a flight for bad weather?

Tags: air-travel, europe, compensation, ec261

My flight got canceled due to bad weather.

Essentially the plane that was supposed to do the flight was not able to land and was diverted to another airport.

As a result, my flight got canceled and I was booked the next day. Other persons got booked the same day, in a later flight from a nearby airport (the one where the airplane landed), but that was not the case for me.

I am aware these compensations can be denied if the reason for cancelation is not the airline's responsibility.

I always find this a bit vague though. As an example, I don't think all the efforts were made to transport us. It was clear that the airplane that was forced to land in a nearby airport continued to serve other scheduled flights. We could have been transported to this airport (50km away) and take this plane as planned (although with a delay).

I would like to better understand what the airline responsibility under this circumstances is.

It's important to mention this happened in the EU.

Comment: Which kind of compensation? (you should get support, food and accommodation, independent of the reason). Also what was the "bad weather"? Exceptional or not? And sadly, you should check possible alternative and ask airline. I found that on call centers many people have zero geographic knowledge e.g. to propose changes, and not just about small airports)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I am referring to the money compensation. I don't know what happened. The sky was clear and there was no rain. According to other passengers this was related with wind and it's a rather common issue in the airport, specially around this time of the year.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly you are entitled to assistance (food, accommodation and communication). However, it is unclear whether you are also entitled to monetary compensation under EU261.
The airline can make the case that it was extraordinary weather circumstances.
You can make the case that although a delay of a few hours was warranted, the airline didn't transported you as early as reasonably possible. It is also possible that they are lying in order to discourage people to make claims.
In this situation I would first try to make an EU261 compensation claim directly to the airline. If the airline refuses, then I would make use of one of those firms that file "flight delay compensation claims".
A friend of mine happened to be in a similar situation, in January 2021 she was stranded for a whole week due to a snow storm. Whereas it was really impossible for the airline to transport her on time, they could have booked her with another airline two days later instead of seven. In an initial claim she got refunded for meals during those seven days, but no extra monetary compensation. She then use a flight delay compensation claim service and almost a year later got the monetary compensation of € 600 (minus 25% fee, but still better than nothing).
I don't remember which service she used, but if it comes to it googling "flight delay compensation" will do.